# where is class SBSMSManager located in ios5?

Tags: iphone, ios5, jailbreak

With ios 4.x it is under SpringBoard, but in ios5 I can't find it.

Where is SBSMSManager in ios5 or which class in ios5 has same functions with SBSMSManager in ios4.x?

Thanks.

Comment: You won't get those kind of answers here, SpringBoard is pretty much completely undocumented and changes with every major (and sometimes not that major) release, your best bet is to either find a really specific forum or IRC channel, or dig though the class dump yourself. To be honest, if you can't do that, maybe you should be doing something simpler.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez thanks for your advice,similar questions about SpringBoard have been asked here and get an answer. I think maybe someone else know the answer and just have a try.

Comment: Find a similar class under ChatKit,thanks for your attention. Hope this can help someone else.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that no `SBSMSManager`, but I get a simulator class called `SMSPluginManager`. Get the binary file named `ChatKit` in your iPhone.The file is under the path  "/System/Library/SpringBoardPlugins/ChatKit.servicebundle/" and then class-dump it.

By the way, SpringBoard will load some plugins that are under the /System/Library/SpringBoardPlugins when it starts. When you can't find a class, try there.